# Scala - Match Tuple of Options

Tags: scala, tuples, pattern-matching, scala-option

I have:

```
val foo = Some(List(1, 2, 3)) -> Some("y")
```

I would like to cast match it:

```
foo match {
    case (Some(x), Some(y)) => println(x + " " + y)
    case _ => println("error")
```

This works fine for `Some(List(1, 2, 3) -> Some("score"))` but fails for `Some(List(1, 2, 3) -> None`, `None -> Some("y")` or `None -> None` with:

```
error: constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
     found   : Some[A]
     required: None.type
error: not found: value ...
```

Why is that?

Of course I could use `getOrElse()` but that does not look so elegant.

Thx a lot,
Karsten

**Update:**

```
foo match {
 case (x: Some[List[Int]], y: Some[Int]) => println(x.get)
 case _ => println("error")
}
```

Fails as well with:

```
error: pattern type is incompatible with expected type;
 found   : Some[Int]
 required: None.type
```

I would think that `case _` would take care of that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is the compiler telling you something. If you have an expression like

```
val foo = Some(List(1, 2, 3)) -> None
```

It will have the type (Some[List[Int]], None.type), which you can easily see from typing in the expression in the scala console

```
scala> val foo = Some(List(1, 2, 3)) -> None
foo: (Some[List[Int]], None.type) = (Some(List(1, 2, 3)),None)
```

So you know at compile time that the second element of the tuple can only ever be None, a match with Some can never succeed. Hence the error message.

If you give foo a less restrictive type it will work.

```
val foo : (Option[List[Int]], Option[String]) = Some(List(1, 2, 3) -> None
```

Note that this is exactly as it should be. Matching on something that can never happen is almost definitely an error. You have to upcast to any to avoid the compile time error (but then you will get a runtime error.

Comment: Hm, that makes sense. However, foo._1 and foo._2 might be defined. That is what I want to know.

Comment: Okay,Now I understand. I thought foo would be of type (Option[List[Int]], Option[Any]).

Comment: You could make it like that. But the scala language designers decided to give Some and None its own type so things like this can be found at compile time. 

This is usually not much an issue in real code, because you would define foo to the most generic type you want to handle, for example (Option[List[Int]], Option[String]).

Comment: Using Scalaz, you can write e.g. `1.some` and `none[Int]`, both of which have the type `Option[Int]`.

Answer (score 2):

In the code below, Scala will get a compilation error on `foo match` but compiles and runs correctly with `foo2`/`foo3`:

```
val foo = None -> None
val foo2: (Option[Any], Option[Any]) = None -> None
val foo3: (Option[Any], Option[Any]) = foo

foo match {
  case (Some(x), Some(y)) => println(x + " " + y)
  case _ => println("error")
}
```